# Spotify Web API Redirect Issue

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

I have set my redirect uri to something like this:
     ../index.php?r=spotifycollegeplaylists/tab/index

I was able to setup the login using this example
https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php

The login is working fine, I can trigger the login popup and I am able to login. Now the problem is with the redirection. After logging in I am redirected to this URL:
    ../index.php%3Fr=spotifycollegeplaylists/tab/index&page=index?code=AQCtOWUzHM

See the problem with the redirect is that it has two "?" 
If i manually change %3F to ? and ?code to &code, the links is working okay.
using the method from the API above how will I be able to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi. We are aware of the issue and it is in our backlog. Unfortunately I cannot give any estimation of when it will be done.

Comment: thanks. at least we have an official note from the devs.. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a query on the Spotify Web API site as well, and I got a feedback from one of their support team / developer.

"I understand your issue and I would recommend that you don't have any query parameters in your callback URLs. We have a known issue in that we don't allow the Redirect URI to include parameters and hopefully this will be fixed soon. Meanwhile, you could use the state parameter that you'll get back when the code is returned through the callback."